# Masstransit request/response does not hit the Fault consumer

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

A similar type of question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499682/masstransit-fault-consumer-not-invoked-for-request-response)

Here is my Requester code

```
            var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(sbc => { sbc.Host(ServiceBusConnectionString); });

            await bus.StartAsync();

            IRequestClient<ScanRequest> client=
                bus.CreateRequestClient<MyRequest>(new Uri("queue:" + QueueName), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(50));
            var response = await client.GetResponse<MyRequestResponse>(scanRequest); //we should get the response here
            await Task.Run(() => Console.ReadKey());

            await bus.StopAsync();
```

I have noticed that , if any error happened into the consumer, It never hit my Fault consumer.

On the other hand, If I send a message through ISendEndPoint (as shown in below code) , The Fault consumer is working perfectly.

```
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = SetupServiceCollection();
        var bus = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IBus>();
        var endpoint = await bus.GetSendEndpoint(new Uri("queue:" + TopicName));
        await endpoint.Send(myRequest);
```

Message type and Namespace has been configured correctly.
Is there any settings I'm missing for request/response pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the answer to the question you linked, *faults* are not published when a `ResponseAddress` is present (which is necessary for request/response) and are instead sent directly to the response address. The fault is subsequently received by the request client and used to throw an exception on the original request `Task`.

There isn't any setting *missing*, it's just how it works.

Comment: thank you for your clarification.
Just for my learning:Though it's by design, Is there any other way we can manually file Fault consumer?

Comment: It's by design, yes. The only way would be to explicitly connect your fault consumer to the bus endpoint (which is used by the request client for responses).